# Populate NAs in a vector using prior non-NA values?

Tags: r

What's a compact/efficient way to populate NAs using the prior non-NA value?  For example:

```
test = c( 1 , 2 , NA , NA , 5 , NA , 9 , NA , NA )
expected = c( 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 5 , 5 , 9 , 9 , 9 )
```

Here, all of the NA values 'look back' to the first non-NA value.  I'm trying to avoid a for loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(test)
[1] 1 2 2 2 5 5 9 9 9
```

Comment: @SFun28 you can't shoot yourself in the foot... YET!