# Add a column with values and NAs

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Populate NAs in a vector using prior non-NA values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023072/populate-nas-in-a-vector-using-prior-non-na-values)

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, but I can't seem to find a resolution to this coding issue. I like to create a column vector that would repeat the same value until the next non `NA` column appears in another column.  So here is a table to illustrate what I like to achieve (column 2).

```
         [,1] [,2]
    [1,] A     a1
    [2,] NA    a1
    [3,] NA    a1
    [4,] B     a2
    [5,] NA    a2
    [6,] A     a3
```

Sorry about the confusion. I must have been really stressed out when writing my post earlier. I've made correction to the column 2 (please see above). After reading your posts, here are the code that I've come up with, although it is not efficient nor elegant:

```
     d <- paste("a", 1:sum(!is.na(column1)), sep="")  # get a1, a2, a3  
     column2 <- rep(NA, length(column1)  #create empty vector w/ column1 length
     column2[!is.na(colum1)] <- d #when col1 has a value, populate col2 with a1   
     e  <- na.locf.default(column2) #fill NAs in col2 with previous value
```

Comment: You have a constant second column...

Comment: or do you want `a1,a1,a1,a2,a2,a3` in the second column ??

Comment: Or maybe even `a1, a1, a1, a4, a4, a6`.

Comment: I *think* your question is not actually a duplicate of the one specified here, but it's very hard to tell.  If you can clarify that it's different (and what you mean/what your desired output is), I would vote to re-open.

Answer (score 3):

Given `x`:

```
x <- c('A', NA, NA, 'B', NA, 'A')
```

For what you want, according to the latest edit of your question:

```
y <- x
y[!is.na(x)] <- seq(sum(!is.na(x)))

paste0('a', na.locf(y))
[1] "a1" "a1" "a1" "a2" "a2" "a3"
```

As @flodel observed, I'm counting the non-NA characters in the string.  This does that directly:

```
> cumsum(!is.na(x))
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3

> paste0('a', cumsum(!is.na(x)))
[1] "a1" "a1" "a1" "a2" "a2" "a3"
```

This result `a1, a1, a1, a4, a4, a6` would seem logical in its own way, showing which value was repeated, but it isn't what you want:

```
y <- x
y[!is.na(x)] <- seq_along(x)[!is.na(x)]

paste0('a', na.locf(y))
[1] "a1" "a1" "a1" "a4" "a4" "a6"
```

For what @Arun's comment indicates (the duplicate question), here is a method:

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(x)
[1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "A"
```

Comment: or simply `paste0("a", cumsum(!is.na(x)))`

Answer (score 2):

You may run into difficulties if the character value is "NA", i.e. an abbreviation for North America, instead of `NA_character_` which somewhat confusingly also gets printed as NA:

```
 c("NA", NA_character_, NA)
#[1] "NA" NA   NA 
is.na(c("NA", NA_character_, NA))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

....  but assuming that is not the problem then do as Matthew suggested:

```
require(zoo)
filled <- na.locf(vec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this pretty succinctly without the `zoo` package using the `rle` function:

```
x <- c('A', NA, NA, 'B', NA, 'A')
x.rle <- rle(replace(x, which(is.na(x)), na.str <- '.'))
x[is.na(x)] <- with(x.rle, rep(values[which(values == na.str) - 1], 
                               lengths[values == na.str]))

# [1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "A"
```