# Idiomatic way to copy cell values "down" in an R vector

Tags: performance, r, loops, vectorization, idioms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Populate NAs in a vector using prior non-NA values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023072/populate-nas-in-a-vector-using-prior-non-na-values)

Is there an idiomatic way to copy cell values "down" in an R vector? By "copying down", I mean replacing NAs with the closest previous non-NA value.

While I can do this very simply with a for loop, it runs very slowly. Any advice on how to vectorise this would be appreciated.

```
# Test code
# Set up test data
len <- 1000000
data <- rep(c(1, rep(NA, 9)), len %/% 10) * rep(1:(len %/% 10), each=10)
head(data, n=25)
tail(data, n=25)

# Time naive method
system.time({
  data.clean <- data;
  for (i in 2:length(data.clean)){
    if(is.na(data.clean[i])) data.clean[i] <- data.clean[i-1]
  }
})

# Print results
head(data.clean, n=25)
tail(data.clean, n=25)
```

Result of test run:

```
> # Set up test data
> len <- 1000000
> data <- rep(c(1, rep(NA, 9)), len %/% 10) * rep(1:(len %/% 10), each=10)
> head(data, n=25)
 [1]  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  3 NA NA NA NA
> tail(data, n=25)
 [1]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA  99999     NA     NA     NA     NA
[11]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA 100000     NA     NA     NA     NA
[21]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
> 
> # Time naive method
> system.time({
+   data.clean <- data;
+   for (i in 2:length(data.clean)){
+     if(is.na(data.clean[i])) data.clean[i] <- data.clean[i-1]
+   }
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   3.09    0.00    3.09 
> 
> # Print results
> head(data.clean, n=25)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
> tail(data.clean, n=25)
 [1]  99998  99998  99998  99998  99998  99999  99999  99999  99999  99999
[11]  99999  99999  99999  99999  99999 100000 100000 100000 100000 100000
[21] 100000 100000 100000 100000 100000
>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023072/populate-nas-in-a-vector-using-prior-non-na-values/9023113#9023113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zoo::na.locf`

Wrapping your code in function `f` (including returning `data.clean` at the end):

```
library(rbenchmark)
library(zoo)

identical(f(data), na.locf(data))
## [1] TRUE

benchmark(f(data), na.locf(data), replications=10, columns=c("test", "elapsed", "relative"))
##            test elapsed relative
## 1       f(data)  21.460   14.471
## 2 na.locf(data)   1.483    1.000
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about idiomatic, but here we identify the non-NA values (`idx`), and the index of the last non-NA value (`cumsum(idx)`)

```
f1 <- function(x) {
    idx <- !is.na(x)
    x[idx][cumsum(idx)]
}
```

which seems to be about 6 times faster than `na.locf` for the example data. It drops leading NA's like `na.locf` does by default, so

```
f2 <- function(x, na.rm=TRUE) {
    idx <- !is.na(x)
    cidx <- cumsum(idx)
    if (!na.rm)
        cidx[cidx==0] <- NA_integer_
    x[idx][cidx]
}
```

which seems to add on about 30% time when `na.rm=FALSE`. Presumably `na.locf` has other merits, capturing more of the corner cases and allowing filling up instead of down (which is an interesting exercise in the `cumsum` world, anyway). It's also clear that we're making at least five allocations of possibly large data -- `idx` (actually, we calculate `is.na()` and it's complement), `cumsum(idx)`, `x[idx]`, and `x[idx][cumsum(idx)]` -- so there's room for further improvement, e.g., in C

Comment: I'd call that idiomatic.  Very nice.  7 times faster than na.locf on my system.