# Replace row of NAs with previous row in R

Tags: r, matrix, na

I was wondering if anyone had a quick and dirty solution to the following problem, I have a matrix that has rows of NAs and I would like to replace the rows of NAs with the previous row (if it is not also a row of NAs).

Assume that the first row is not a row of NAs

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at `na.locf` from the `zoo` package.

Comment: I thought he said he did not want multiple NA's filled in?

Answer (score 4):

Adapted from an answer to this question: [Idiomatic way to copy cell values "down" in an R vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449717/idiomatic-way-to-copy-cell-values-down-in-an-r-vector/14449823#14449823)

```
f <- function(x) {
  idx <- !apply(is.na(x), 1, all)
  x[idx,][cumsum(idx),]
}

x <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA), b=c(4, 5, NA, 6, NA, 7))

> x
   a  b
1  1  4
2  2  5
3 NA NA
4  3  6
5 NA NA
6 NA  7

> f(x)
     a b
1    1 4
2    2 5
2.1  2 5
4    3 6
4.1  3 6
6   NA 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to think of times you may have two all NA rows in a row.

```
#create a data set like you discuss (in the future please do this yourself)
set.seed(14)
x <- matrix(rnorm(10), nrow=2)
y <- rep(NA, 5)
v <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, sample(list(x, x, y), 10, TRUE))
```

One approach:

```
NArows <- which(apply(v, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))))          #find all NAs
notNA <- which(!seq_len(nrow(v)) %in% NArows)                    #find non NA rows
rep.row <- sapply(NArows, function(x) tail(notNA[x > notNA], 1)) #replacement rows
v[NArows, ] <- v[rep.row, ]                                      #assign
v                                                                #view
```

This would not work if your first row is all NAs.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a loop, here assuming that 1 is not NA as indicated:

```
fill = data.frame(x=c(1,NA,3,4,5))
for (i in 2:length(fill)){
  if(is.na(fill[i,1])){ fill[i,1] = fill[(i-1),1]}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `m` is your matrix, this is your quick and **dirty** solution:

```
sapply(2:nrow(m),function(i){ if(is.na(m[i,1])) {m[i,] <<- m[(i-1),] } })
```

Note it uses the ugly (and dangerous) `<<-` operator.

Comment: `<<-` within the function passed to `sapply` means that you should use a `for` loop (or an entirely different approach).

Answer (score 0):

Matthew's example:

```
x <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA), b=c(4, 5, NA, 6, NA, 7))
 na.rows <- which( apply( x , 1, function(z) (all(is.na(z)) ) ) )
 x[na.rows , ] <- x[na.rows-1, ]
 x
#---
   a b
1  1 4
2  2 5
3  2 5
4  3 6
5  3 6
6 NA 7
```

Obviously a first row with all NA's would present problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward and conceptually perhaps the simplest one-liner:

```
x <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA), b=c(4, 5, NA, 6, NA, 7))

   a  b
1  1  4
2  2  5
3 NA NA
4  3  6
5 NA NA
6 NA  7

x1<-t(sapply(1:nrow(x),function(y) ifelse(is.na(x[y,]),x[y-1,],x[y,])))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1    4   
[2,] 2    5   
[3,] 2    5   
[4,] 3    6   
[5,] 3    6   
[6,] NA   7
```

To put the column names back, just use colnames(x1)<-colnames(x)